# Javascript string formatting

Tags: c#, javascript

In my C# webapplication, I have to pass this below html string to a client side function by clicking on a server side button code. I am using Firefox browser.

htmlString is:

```
<div id='divPopUpToXyz.abc@def.com'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img width='10' src='../images/cross.gif' onclick='deleteDiv(1,'ToXyz.abc@def.com','To')>
       </td>
       <td>
         Xyz.abc@def.com
       </td> 
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

On server side i am using this to call the required JS function:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "returnValue('" + htmlString+ "');", true);
```

But I am getting an error like this:

> "missing ) after argument list"

I checked through firebug, and found that the htmlstring gets distorted like this:

```
<div id='divPopUpToXyz.abc@def.com'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="../images/cross.gif" onclick="deleteDiv(1,"     toXyz.abc@def.com','to')="" width="10">
        </td>
        <td>
          Xyz.abc@def.com
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody> 
 </table>
 </div>
```

I am not getting why it is changing like this.

Please suggest some way out.

Comment: Your `htmlString` includes single quotes-within-single quotes (look at your `onclick` handler, for one). You then included it in `returnValue()` wrapped in *more* single quotes. The browser is making as much sense of all this as it can. Get `htmlString`'s contents properly quoted on their own, then use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` to prepare it for inclusion in the `returnValue()` call

Comment: where's the code that initializes htmlString (What you have posted is not a valid string)

Comment: you probably want to add the html content somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the value you expect to be passing

```
onclick='deleteDiv(1,'ToXyz.abc@def.com','To'
```

is interpreted as two attributes

```
onclick='deleteDiv(1,'
ToXyz.abc@def.com','To'=""
```

because of the first ' following 1, is terminating the onclick attribute assignment

change the htmlString assignement to

```
var htmlString = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(@"<div id='divPopUpToXyz.abc@def.com'><table><tr><td><img width='10' src='../images 
/cross.gif' onclick='deleteDiv(1,""ToXyz.abc@def.com"",""To"")'>   
 </td><td>Xyz.abc@def.com</td> 
 </tr></table></div>");
```

and you should be good to go